# Iterate txt file python

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate over a simple .txt file containing a bunch of recipes. 
What I want is for my loop to find all sections beginning with -Ingredients, add every line of ingredient 
to a list, move on to the next set of ingredients and add those until I have a complete list consisting
of all ingredients in the file. The general filestructure looks like so:

- Pasta Salad
- Description:
  bla
  bla
- Ingredients:
- ingredient 1
- ingredient 2
- ingredient 3
- Preperation:
  bla
  bla
  bla

Here is a sample of my code so far:

```
import os
import sys

def get_ingredients_from_file():
    recipe_file = open("/Filepath/", "r")
    final_ingredients_list = list()

    for line in recipe_file:                                                                                   
        if line.startswith("-Ingredients"):                             
            # append every line until next section, then move on to next
            # ingredient section
```

Comment: Does your file contain bullet points? Please turn the file in your question into a code block that exactly matches the file you are reading.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: Check if my answer below makes sense @henning

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary list to append ingredients to, and then when you encounter
 a line `- Ingredients:`, you append this list to a bigger list, and do the same thing again.

```
def get_ingredients_from_file():

    result = []
    with open('file.txt') as fp:
        li = []
        for line in fp:
            #Append the ingredients to temporary list
            if line.startswith('*'):
                li.append(line.replace('*','').strip())
            #Get a new list and append it to result
            elif line.startswith("- Ingredients"):
                li = []
                result.append(li)
    return result

print(get_ingredients_from_file())
```

So if the file looks like

```
- Pasta Salad
- Description:
    bla
    bla

- Ingredients:
* ingredient 1
* ingredient 2
* ingredient 3

- Preperation:
    bla
    bla
    bla

- Ingredients:
* ingredient 4
* ingredient 5
* ingredient 6
```

The output will look like

```
[['ingredient 1', 'ingredient 2', 'ingredient 3'], 
['ingredient 4', 'ingredient 5', 'ingredient 6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
def get_ingredients_from_file():
    recipe_file = open("./extractIngredients_input.txt", 'r')
    final_ingredients_list = list()
    add_ingredients = list()
    pick = False
    for line in recipe_file:
        if line.startswith("- Ingredients"):
            pick = True
            add_ingredients = list()
        elif line.startswith("-") and pick:
            pick = False
            final_ingredients_list.append(add_ingredients)
        elif pick and (len(line) > 1):
            add_ingredients.append(line[2:-1])
    if pick:
        final_ingredients_list.append(add_ingredients)
    return final_ingredients_list
```

It's not exactly a "append every line until next section, then move on to next 
ingredient section" structure, but it works fine.

On another note, if `os` and `sys` are not used somewhere else, I don't think you need them here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the sections in your txt file starts with a "-" you could create two String flags and use those as checks in a nested for loop like so:

```
import os
import sys

def get_ingredients_from_file():
  recipe_file = open("/Filepath/", "r")
  final_ingredients_list = list()
  string_flag1 = "-Ingredients"
  string_flag2 = "-"

  for line in recipe_file:                                                                                   
    if line.startswith(string_flag1):           #Line is ingredients
      for line in recipe_file:                  
        if not line.startswith(string_flag2):   #Loop until second string flag is encountered
          final_ingredients_list.append(line)   #append lines to the list
        else:
          break
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you hate ifs and elses, and assuming you only have one Ingredients section, here's a way doing it with regular expressions.

```
import re

def get_ingredients():
    text = open('recipe_test.txt', 'r').read()
    ingredients = re.search(r'- Ingredients:(.*?)- Preperation:', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
    ingredients = ingredients.splitlines()
    ingredients = list(filter(lambda x: x, ingredients))
    return ingredients

def main():
    ingredients = get_ingredients()
    for ingredient in ingredients:
        print(ingredient)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Explanation of get_ingredients() as follows:

1. Read the entire file into text.
2. From text, extract all the text between "- Ingredients:" and "- Preperation:"
3. Create a list of all the ingredients. At this point the list contains empty lines.
4. Filter out empty lines.
5. Return the ingredients.

main() just runs get_ingredients() and neatly(?) prints out the ingredients.

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_ingredients_from_file():
  recipe_file = open("/Filepath/", "r")
  recipe_text = recipe_file.readlines()
  recipe_list = []
  i = 1
  for line in recipe_text:
    if line.startswith('- Ingredients'):
      while recipe_text[recipe_text.index(line) + i].startswith('* '):
        recipe_list.append(recipe_text[recipe_text.index(line) + i])
        i += 1
```

I'm new to this still, but this will look for lines beginning with "- Ingredients" and then check if the lines coming after start with a "* ", and if so, will be added to your recipe_list. Then you can do whatever with that list.

Comment: You can’t index an open file like that.  And not resetting `i` looks like a mistake.